# HTML5 canvas rotation not centered at origin

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

The HTML below is a standalone file to reproduce my bug.

I would expect the code below to show the orange dot rotate in place as a move the slider.

I first translate such that the point is centered at the origin. I assumed that a rotation would then not affect the point, however, it does.

Is there something I've misunderstood about how these canvas operations work?

```js
var $ = (s) => document.querySelector(s);
const ctx = $("#c").getContext("2d");

function drawDot(x, y, r, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
}

function render() {
    let x = 100, y = 100;
    const radians = Math.PI * $("#r").value / 180;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.save()
    drawDot(x, y, 5, 'red')
    ctx.translate(-x, -y);
    drawDot(x, y, 100, 'pink')
    ctx.rotate(radians);
    drawDot(x, y, 50, 'orange')
    ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```html
<div>
    <canvas id="c" height=200 width=200 />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="-180" max="180" value="0" id="r" />
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h0ykb3v2/ or https://jsfiddle.net/h0ykb3v2/1/ , not sure what you are really after, but the point is 1.translate to pivot, 2. rotate, 3. come back to origin, 4. draw at expected coords